# How to construct JSON array with Parson?

Tags: c, json, parsing, serialization, microcontroller

I'm using [Parson](https://github.com/kgabis/parson) library to send sensor data from a MCU to a server. I want to generate the following JSON, but **I can't figure out how to generate the arrays** ("sensors" and "measurements").

```
{
  "systemInfo:": {
  "hubId": "1234",
  "battery:": {
      "value": 3.3,
      "unit": "V"
   }
 },
 "sensors": [
 {
   "name": "S1",
   "measurements:": [
    {
      "measuredValue": "val",
      "value": 123,
      "unit": "unit"
    }
  ]
 },
 {
   "name": "S2",
   "measurements": [
    {
      "measuredValue": "val1",
      "value": 123,
      "unit": "unit1"
    },
    {
      "measuredValue": "val2",
      "value": 123,
      "unit": "unit2"
    }
  ]
 },
 {
   "name": "s3",
   "measurements": [
    {
      "measuredValue": "val",
      "value": 120,
      "unit": "unit"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

There is an example on the GitHub page (serialization_example), that generates an array by parsing a string:

```
json_object_dotset_value(root_object, "contact.emails",
                         json_parse_string("[\"email@example.com\", \"email2@example.com\"]"));
```

but I would like to generate it using the API functions and not by manually constructing the string like in the example above. E.g., by using

```
json_object_set_string()
json_object_dotset_string()
json_object_dotset_number() etc.
```

**Is it possible? Or the API does not offer this functionality?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to my problem, but instead in found another library, [cJSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON), that can do what I need.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck at this same point but as I looked into parson.h and parson.c I found support for Json_Array. here is just a sample code to help.

```
    //creating a Json_Array
    JSON_Value *branch = json_value_init_array();
    JSON_Array *leaves = json_value_get_array(branch);
    
    //creating measurement Json

    JSON_Value *leaf_value = json_value_init_object();
    JSON_Object *leaf_object = json_value_get_object(leaf_value);
    json_object_set_number(leaf_object,"name1",123);
    json_object_set_number(leaf_object,"name2",456);
    json_object_set_number(leaf_object,"name3",789);
    json_array_append_value(leaves,leaf_value);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You have a bug, fix second line with `JSON_Array *leaves = json_value_get_array(branch);`,

thanks

Comment: Awesome! You saved me. Would make it easier to understand if you add a string representation of the JSON that you are building. But thanks for the response!